# GDB says symbol 'stdout' not in context

Tags: gdb

I have a debugging macro defined in **.gdbinit** says:

```
define printinfo
  pinfo(stdout, $arg0)
end
```

however when I run gdb and use `printinfo somedata`, the gdb throws me:

```
No symbol "stdout" in current context.
```

As I know stdout is a standard file descriptor in c. But it failed to find it here.

Need your help!

Comment: Standard, I dunno... `<stdio.h>` defines `stdout` to a `FILE*`. `<unistd.h>` defines STDOUT_FILENO to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No symbol "stdout" in current context

You are likely using a libc version which uses `#define stdout` to something else. Preprocess a file containing this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 ----before----
 stdout
 ----after----
```

then look at what `stdout` expanded to. Chances are it's not `stdout` anymore after preprocessing.